# Simple subgroup proof, would love some advice

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Let $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$ be the group of invertible $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries.
Consider $H$ which is the subset of matrices of the form

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & b \\ 0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$

with $b$ an integer. Is $H$ a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$? Explain your answer.

well when $b = 0$ we have the identity, and $\det |A| = 1$ so it is invertible and the inverse is simply  $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -b \\ 0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$ for all $b$ in the integers. I seem a little lost on closure. Clearly $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -b \\ 0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$ multiplied by $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & a \\ 0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$ where $a$ is in the integers yields

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -b+a \\ 0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$ and $a - b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers is an integer. So we got non empty and we got $A^{-1} B$.

So we're done?

Comment: You're done, yes.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you i assumed i did it wrong because it was easy :)

Comment: When checking if a subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup, the same three things needs to be checked every time: 1) that the identity element is in $H$. 2) That the inverse of any element of $H$ is in $H$. 3) That the product of any two elements of $H$ is contained in $H$. Most of the time these three points are very easy to check. At least in exercises given in books.

Comment: Yes you are done. Just a comment: once you know $H$ is nonempty, it is enough just to show the last part, which is technically not closure, but for groups even stronger than closure as you indicate in your second last sentence. You have done more than you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much. Use any $b \in \mathbb{R}$, not $-b$ to underline it's a generic real number, and as in your calculation with $-b$, you get a product matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a+b \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} := C.$$ As $a+b \in \mathbb{R}$, $C \in H$, so $H$ is closed.